# Performance of initialising integer array from `MaybeUninit<[{integer}; N]>`

Tags: rust

Say I have an array of primitive integers of length `N`, and I want to create a new array of the same length by applying a function to each element in the original array. For example, with the `swap_bytes` method:

```rs
let arr: [u64; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let output: [u64; 4] = [1u64.swap_bytes(), 2u64.swap_bytes(), 3u64.swap_bytes(), 4u64.swap_bytes()];
// Just an example to show the desired output, 
// obviously a generic function wouldn't use this code
```

My question is: would it be faster to make the output array a `[MaybeUninit<u64>; 4]` to begin with, or would it be just as fast to initialise the output array with zeros (`[0u64; 4]`), as the element type  of the array is a primitive integer?

So basically I'm asking which of these two pieces of code would be faster, and why:

```rs
let arr: [u64; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let mut out = MaybeUninit::uninit_array::<4>();
for i in 0..4 {
    out[i] = MaybeUninit::new(arr[i].swap_bytes());
}
MaybeUninit::array_assume_init(out)
```

or

```rs
let arr: [u64; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let mut out = [0u64; 4];
for i in 0..4 {
    out[i] = arr[i].swap_bytes();
}
out
```

Comment: there is not a definitive answer to that, compiler could optimize it away or not.

Comment: If the compiler does not optimise the zeroing operation away, then that is a needless operation that the `MaybeUninit` version would avoid.

Comment: [IME](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=32937e29f52408eb37e4c42fd8555154), doing `for (d, s) in out.iter_mut().zip(&arr) { *d = *s }`, the compiler will optimize out the zero initalization.

Comment: And indeed on the Playground the zero initialisation is optimised out of [the OP's version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=4b19bbfd3f14fee34e4a93181eb6c56e) too.